# Dumbledores "Greater Good"

Tags: translation

In Harry Potter Fan Fiction Romanen rechtfertigt Albus Dumbledore seine manchmal moralisch zweifelhaften Taten mit der Begründung, sie seien wegen des "Greater Good" notwendig. Verwendet wird der Term häufig in Verbindung mit dem trivialen Kategorischen Imperativ "doing what's right and not what's easy".

Was wäre eine passende Übersetzung?

- Für das Allgemeinwohl
- Für das Große und Ganze
- Oder...

Comment: @Janka hat die perfekte Übersetzung. `Zweck` passt auch zur Redewendung "Der Zweck heiligt die Mittel." Die Frage ist eigetnlich nicht besonders spezifisch mit Harry Potter verbunden, deswegen könnte man üblerlegen, ob man den Titel nochmal etwas allgemeiner formuliert.

Comment: Nach kurzer Recherche scheint der Ausdruck "Greater Good" in keinem der originalen 7 Bücher vorzukommen. Also auch nicht in der deutschen Übersetzung, so dass man sich auf diese beziehen könnte. Ich denke daher ebenfalls, dass @Janka die perfekte Übersetzung bereits nannte.

Comment: @mtwde, als Potterhead muss ich das korrigieren. Grindelwald schreibt in seinem Brief an den jugendlichen Dumbledore: "We seize controll for the greater good" (Buch 7). Die deutsche Übersetzung ist, glaube ich, "für das größere Wohl".

Answer (score 5):

Grindelwald schreibt in seinem Brief an den jugendliche Dumbledore (Buch 7):

> We seize control for the greater good.

In der deutschen Fassung wurde das übersetzt als

> Wir übernehmen die Kontrolle für das größere Wohl.

"Für das Größere Wohl" stand auch über dem Eingang Gefängnisses Nurmengard, in das Grindelwald seine Gegner gesteckt hat:

> In zynischer Verklärung seiner Gewaltherrschaft brachte Grindelwald seine Losung "Für das Größere Wohl" auch über dem Eingang von Nurmengard an. Was wohl nicht zufällig an das nazionalsozialistische
>   Motto Arbeit macht frei über dem Eingang von Konzentrationslagern der
>   Nazis erinnert. JK Rowling erklärte, dass Grindelwald sozusagen das
>   magische Gegenstück zu Adolf Hitler sei (JK Rowling Interview vom
>   16.07.2005 Teil 3).
>   Quelle: [http://de.harry-potter.wikia.com/wiki/Größeres_Wohl](http://de.harry-potter.wikia.com/wiki/Gr%C3%B6%C3%9Feres_Wohl)

Comment: _für das größere Wohl_ unterscheidet sich von _zu einem höheren Zweck_ jedenfalls dadurch, dass es nicht Gefahr läuft, religiöse/spirituelle Assoziationen zu wecken (vgl. englisch: _a higher purpose [of life]_), was gewünscht oder auch nicht gewünscht sein mag, jedenfalls aber m.E. dem englischen Original entspricht.

Comment: gleichzeitig ist es aber auch nicht idiomatisch und wirkt sehr holprig.

Comment: Inwiefern weckt denn denn "für einen höheren Zweck" spirituelle Assoziationen?

Answer (score -1):

Annäherung für den Ausdruck »wegen des *Greater Good*«:

> »Warum schlägst du ihm den Kopf ab?«
>   »Aus übergeordneten Gründen.«

Comment: Sorry, aber das ist wirklich kein gutes Deutsch und Janka hat im Kommentar auf die Frage im Kommentar zur Frage bereits besser beantwortet. Daher gebe ich hier -1